# I am trying to make a program which writes to a file and then finds what has been writen in that file

Tags: python

```
a=("Hello")
f  = open("hello.csv","a")
f.write(a)
g=str.find(a)
if g== (True):
                print("True")
f.close()
```

This code is is not working it is showing up that find() requires one argument and that 0 were given when I clearly stated a which is ("Hello")

Comment: @Hackaholic that's not a terribly helpful comment...

Answer (score 2):

In Python:

```
Class.method(instance)
```

is equivalent to

```
instance.method()
```

`str` is a class, so `str.find(a)` is equivalent to `a.find()`, which is clearly missing the second string to be found:

```
>>> "hello".find()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    "hello".find()
TypeError: find/rfind/index/rindex() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
>>> str.find("hello")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    str.find("hello")
TypeError: find/rfind/index/rindex() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
>>> "hello".find("e")
1
>>> str.find("hello", "e")
1
```

You need to specify **two strings** - one to look in, one to find, either as `look_in.find(to_find)`, or `str.find(look_in, to_find)` (the former is more conventional, and reads better).

---

Also, rather than `if g== (True):`, you should write simply `if g:`. Have a look at [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @Hackaholic what? Is that a question?

Comment: may be i dont get it `I am trying to make a program which writes to a file and then finds what has been writen in that file`

Comment: @Hackaholic this isn't a code-writing service; I have corrected the OP's use of `find`, once they understand how to apply it it is up them to determine how to get the two strings (`look_in` and `to_find`, in my answer) they want to use.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
a = "Hello"   # no need of brackets 
f  = open("hello.csv","a")
f.write(a)
f.close()
f  = open("hello.csv","r")
f = f.read()
if f.find(a)>0:       # find returns position of substring if found else -1
    print True
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in `w+` ([see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)) mode it will generate a file Name [`hello.csv`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html). and use `file.seek` to read the file

```
a = ("Hello")
with open("hello.csv", 'w+') as f:
    f.write(a)
    f.seek(0)
    print f.read()
```

from